# How can I make a link to a specific anchor tag on a different html page?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make a link to a specific anchor tag on a different html page? When I make the reference

```
a href="index.php#home"
```

It redirects me to the right page and to the specific anchor, at the top of the page.

**Update :** It actually takes me to the right anchor, but 1 block above.

Comment: Link look reasonable. Without [MCVE] it is not possible to suggest why it does not work for your particular case.

Comment: I think I figured out what's a problem, I am using ninja slider, and when I am redirecting, it first goes to the anchor and when slider is loaded it takes me 1 block above, do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try repositionning your anchor in the code itself, wherever it is written right now. If you had a complete example in your post, we'd be able to help you out better.